# Taking Result as Float in Procedured SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here I have a little complicated SQL command. How can I take its result as float?

Where should I put `CAST` and `AS FLOAT` ?

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = T2.fm_hour
from T T1 join (Select distinct name,sum(fm) over (partition by name)/60 fm_hour
                from T) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: what value do you want to `cast`?

Comment: i want to cast, fm_hour value

Comment: I guess you want the result of dividing by 60 as a float. Try to divid by `60.0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways that you can do this.

You can cast the value when it is set in the update:

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = cast(T2.fm_hour as float)
from T T1 
join 
(
   Select distinct name, sum(fm) over (partition by name)/60 fm_hour
   from T
) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```

Or can cast the 60:

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = T2.fm_hour
from T T1 
join 
(
   Select distinct name, sum(fm) over (partition by name)/ cast(60 as float) fm_hour
   from T
) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```

Or you can just divide by 60.0:

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = T2.fm_hour
from T T1 
join 
(
   Select distinct name, sum(fm) over (partition by name)/ 60.0 fm_hour
   from T
) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
update T1 set T1.fm_hour = T2.fm_hour
from T T1 join (Select distinct name,cast(sum(fm) over (partition by name)/60 as float) fm_hour
                from T) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
where T1.work_type = 'out'
```